Accidental murder during war
Do the laws of accidental murder/goel ha'dam apply during a war? For instance if during battle a Jew accidentally kills another Jew in such a way as would warrant the application of the laws of accidental murder, i.e. running away to a city of refuge. Or since war is an inherently different and life-threatening situation are these halachos not applicable?

Could you clarify how the accidental murder took place? Are you perhaps referring to what's called friendly fire? In that case I think that's usually characterized as poshes rather than ones. Or perhaps you are simply referring to an accident that happened coincidentally at the same time as a war? If the latter I'm not sure there's any logical reason for it to be different

As explained in the mishna Makkos perek 2, the accidental באונס murderer is fully exempt from city of refuge. Only if murder is due to negligence בשוגג - that warrants city of refuge, however not if close to accidental שוגג קרוב לאוסס. If negligence is close to being intentional שוגג קרוב למזיד, the person cannot be admitted to the city of refuge and has to be in permanent exile. Please modify the question.

@Dude and @Y DJ Why would friendly fire necessarily be pshia?

@ba my concern is the word "accidental" does not mean city of refuge. If it is accidental - there is no city of refuge. If it is friendly fire due to negligence -then there is city of refuge, but not negligent close to intentional.

@ba because of the basics for weapons safety and because of the controls that are used in terms of using a weapon in the military by leaders. Additionally it's every soldiers responsibility to have control over themselves and their weapons. It may be conceivable to in theory have an accident but in reality it doesn't really work like that.

"Accidental murder" is a contradiction in terms

@Dude that's not necessarily true. Unfortunately it has happened in the current war, that a soldier fired at terrorists, and one shot went through two windows to the neighboring street and hit and killed another soldier. That's probably Ones

@YDJ I see what you mean, but I think the use of "accident" for שוגג is correct, and "negligence" would imply פשיעה (see definition of accident in this legal dictionary: "not deliberately caused" and "not inevitable"; using this terminology: שוגג קרוב לאונס = inevitable accident, and שוגג קרוב למזיד = negligent accident)
